# W3C Speech To Text: output values as you speak

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, speech-to-text

I've been using the [W3C Speech Synthesizer](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#speechsynthesisvoice) for the web in my app. I'd like the words to start appearing as I speak them. This is because I want the user to have near-instant feedback on the current word they're speaking. Currently, the `result` events in the spec wait to append the entire array after a second or so of not speaking.

I've looked through the standards, but I've only found that it waits a bit to construct the final results list from the result event:

**5.1.3 SpeechRecognition Events**

result event: Fired when the speech recognizer returns a result

**5.1.8 SpeechRecognitionEvent**

results attribute: The array of all current recognition results for this session.

I've also tried retrieving the results in `onstart` and `onpause` methods:

```
            recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition()

            recognition.onstart = function (event) {
                //append word
            };

            recognition.onpause = function (event) {
                //append word
            };
```

Anyone know a way to accomplish this "typing" effect of the words as you speak?

---

The other issue is, if the user stops speaking for a sec, and the results list is compiled (IE, the `result event` is fired), and they go to speak again, the results list is not updated.

This happens even if I set `recognition.continuous = true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it from Google Developers [Introduction Video](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk---Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API?hl=en).

In addition to `recognition.continuous = true`, you also need `recognition.interimResults = true;`.

Then need to modify your logic slightly in the `onresult` handler to account for interim results:

```
recognition.onresult = function (event) {
  var final = "";
  var interim = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
    if (event.results[i].final) {
      final += event.results[i][0].transcript;
    } else {
      interim += event.results[i][0].transcript;
    }
  }
  final_span.innerHTML = final;
  interim_span.innerHTML = interim;
}
```